# Google foobar 2019, tests pass on my local machine (IDE) but fail on foobar

Tags: java

I've just started the Google foobar challenge and I'm having issue where my code passes the sample input test cases on my local machine, but fail when I submit to Foobar.

This is a very basic level 1 question so I'm assuming the problem has something to do with either the code format or output that Foobar is expecting?

Here is the sample test #1 given by Foobar:

```
-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution("code")
Output:
    100100101010100110100010
```

To test my theory I have my code just return the expected answer for the first test case.

Here is my code:

```
public class Solution {

  public Solution() {
  }

  public String solution(String s) {
    return "100100101010100110100010";
  }
}
```

But when I verify my solution test case one fails:

```
foobar:~/braille-translation dude.abides$ verify Solution.java 
Verifying solution...
Test 1 failed 
Test 2 failed 
Test 3 failed 
Test 4 failed  [Hidden]
Test 5 failed  [Hidden]
Test 6 failed  [Hidden]
Test 7 failed  [Hidden]
```

I'm pretty sure this proves the problem is not on my side? Or what am I missing?

This is a timed problem and I'm running out of time so any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my code, of course, and not with foobar.

foobar provides a stub for class that looks like this:

```
public​ ​class​ ​Solution​ ​{
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​public​ ​static​ ​String​ ​solution(String​ ​s)​ ​{
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​ //​ ​Your​ ​code​ ​here
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​}
}
```

And foobar will call the code like this: `Solution.solution("code")`

I failed to notice that the method is **static**.

I had put all my initialization code in the class constructor, which was never being called.

I hope this helps someone else in the future!